# How do I install programs in /usr/local if they shouldn't be compiled by root?

Tags: security, software-installation, compiling, root

Somewhere in the back of my brain is the memory of reading a cautionary internet voice warning against compiling (i.e. running `make`) as the root user. Perhaps it's something like [this story](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/linux-programming/42383-never-compile-root.html) cprogramming.com.

At the same time, it's generally advised that the root user owns `/usr/local` and its subdirectories.

This makes it cumbersome to install software from source:

```
# as root
mkdir program
chown user.user program

# as user
wget/curl/mv program.tar.gz program/.
cd program/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make

# as root
make install
```

Is this the simplest, most proper way to install software from source system-wide? Is it true that `make` is dangerous as root but `make install` isn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about risk mitigation; if `make` does something destructive, you can only lose whatever data was modifiable (or deletable) by the user running it. So you run `make` as a plain user to limit the scope to that user's files, and you run `make install` as `root` because you have to if you want to install to `/usr/local` typically.

Note that in the example you give, there's no need to create `program` as `root`; download your tarball to your home directory or some other directory you can write to, extract it, configure and build as a plain user:

```
$ wget ...
$ tar xf program...tar.gz
$ cd program...
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
$ make
```

Generally `/usr/local` is the default prefix so it can be omitted.

If you want to maximise safety, use a dedicated user to build software (so you don't lose your own files if something goes wrong), and of course read the build system at least. `make -n` can help: it will show you what would be done without actually doing anything. You could also create a special user or group with write access to `/usr/local` and use that when running `make install`.

Answer (score 2):

It comes down to trust vs convenience. True, `make` might be insecure, but then so might `make install`. It's just that the surface attack area should (hopefully) be smaller for `make install`, and it's more likely a quick perusal of the `Makefile` will spot anything strange. However, installing software into the `$PATH` is risky regardless of who has compiled it, so arguably the whole issue is somewhat moot.

Personally, I often put myself and other admins in the `staff` group and give that group write permissions to most of the directories under `/usr/local`. I can then play the `tar` .. `configure` .. `make` game without needing root privileges at all, and `sudo` helps me out with installation of the binaries.

No it's not perfect. Yes it's very convenient.

Comment: In Debian, the group that owns files in `/usr/local` is "staff", by default. I don't know about other distributions. So the user running `make install` just needs to be in "staff".